# GraphQL Relay nodeInterface

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, relay

I'm trying to merge 2 schemas that implements their own nodeDefinitions. One schema uses globalId, like so:

```js
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  interfaces: () => [nodeInterface],

  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('User'),
...
```

And the other schema implements this kind of node Interface, with its own custom id

```js
const Node = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: 'Node',
    description: 'Generic Node to fetch single parts of the graph.', 
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(entries.types.ariseId) }
    },
```

Error

```
{
 "errors": [
{
  "message": "Interface field Node.id expects type ID! but Property.id 
   is type ariseId!.\n\nInterface field Node.id expects type ID! but 
   SpaceType.id is type ariseId!.\n\nInterface field Node.id expects 
   type ID! but Availability.id is type ariseId!.\n\nInterface field 
   Node.id expects type ID! but RatePlan.id is type 
   ariseId!.\n\nInterface field Node.id expects type ID! but 
   Traveler.id is type ariseId!.\n\nInterface field Node.id expects 
   type ID! but Partner.id is type ariseId!.\n\nInterface field 
   Node.id expects type ID! but Reservation.id is type ariseId!."
     }
   ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Relay server spec](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm) says that the type of `Node` must be exactly

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}
```

so probably your second fragment is wrong (or at least not conforming to the spec).

That having been said, [the ID type](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-ID) can have a representation of any string or numeric value, so it's probably straightforward to change your second fragment to use plain `ID`.  That's true in both the definition of the `Node` interface and in the `id` field itself.